# React Native lottie module causes error with expo 34.0.0

Tags: react-native, expo

try running npm start on react native with expo 34.0.0 and i have this error:

```
Unable to resolve "lottie-react-native" from "node_modules\react-native-animated-loader\src\index.js"
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
```

-Im using Node version: 12.5.0
-expo version: 34.0.0

I found this solution in this thread:
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/4455

I put the following in app.js

```
import { YellowBox } from "react-native";
// Remove this and YellowBox after this issue is resolved https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/4455
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(["UIManager['getConstants']"]);
```

But I still have the error
How can i fix this error.
i'm stuck with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to fix this problem if someone has the same:

-delete your node_modules

-npm install -save lottie-react-native

-npm install

**then if you have another error:**

\node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js

change this:

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

to:

```
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```